# The chrome browser default setting of fonts

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts

I just change the font style in the setting of **Chrome browser**, they are `Standard font`, `Serif font`, `Sans-serif font` and `Fixed font`, i chose another font for every item, then save it and quickly feel the web page looks so uncomfortable T_T.....and I forgot the default font, maybe the default is the best one -_-;

So could someone help me and provide the default font setting? thanks a lot ^_^.

Comment: I went to `chrome://settings/reset` and pressed "Restore settings to their original defaults" and it **didn't work**, it reset a bunch of my browser settings and deleted my cookies but my custom fonts stayed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Font size: 16
- Standard font, Serif font: *Times New Roman*
- Sans-serif font: *Arial*
- Fixed-width font: *Consolas*

Comment: How does one know this answer?

Comment: Times New Roman not found :(

Comment: I don't remember that I have changed the fonts. My current Fixed-width font is Osaka. And I cannot find Consolas in the list. Are you sure your answer is correct? Is there any official document (like the source code) we can refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Just open `chrome://settings/fonts` and you will see the `Customize fonts` settings. Note that these settings may be different when you change the default language used to display the Google Chrome UI.

[Customize fonts settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjgNa.png)

Reference : https://www.maketecheasier.com/change-default-font-chrome/

Answer (score 2):

i tried @pragman solution and got the same fonts for all styles, but not defaults :(
so i removed the `webkit` option entirely, it was:

```
  "webkit": {
    "webprefs": {
      "default_fixed_font_size": 13,
      "default_font_size": 16,
      "fonts": {
        "sansserif": {
          "Zyyy": "Custom"
        },
        "serif": {
          "Zyyy": "Custom"
        },
        "standard": {
          "Zyyy": "Custom"
        }
      },
      "minimum_font_size": 0
    }
  },
```

my `Preferences` file was too big for vim editor and i got a new file with command-line JSON processor

```bash
jq -c "del(.webkit)" Preferences > Preferences.new
```

Comment: what was the effect of this change?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the original fonts, here's how to do it:

First, close Google Chrome, so your changes don't get overwritten.

Go to your Google Chrome settings folder, in Ubuntu, i found it in `.config/google-chrome`

In this folder, open up the file `Default/Preferences`,

Search and replace references to your fonts in the file with the string "Custom". In my case they were all at the end of the file, so it was easy to replace.

After this, open up Google Chrome again, and your fonts will be reset.

Comment: Is the specific string important, or could "Custom" be any string that doesn't match a font?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. On ChromeOS, the default fonts are actually: Arimo (sans-serif), Tinos (serif), and Cousine (monospace).

I was having a similar problem to you, but when I plugged in these fonts, everything was back to normal.

Comment: How is this better from acceptec answer? More than 4 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

@pragman, Thanks for the answer, I am facing a similar kind of issue, where fonts can not be reset to default "customized" when we go to the font settings. I did modify the Preferences file as mentioned, somehow it was getting overridden again and again. So I removed the .config/google-chrome folder, which does a hard reset kind of effect and now the font settings show a "customized" value in the drop box

Comment: Does this solve the problem or does the problem still persists?

Comment: Hi Kuldeep, this site does not run like a forum.  And since this is not an answer, it may get deleted.  Please feel free to ask your own question instead.